# File reading in binary C++

Tags: c++, file

How to read a file in binary line by line in a char array in C++ ?
like this:

```
struct packet
{
    unsigned int ack;
    char data[994];
    int sequence_number;
    unsigned long checksum;
    int lenghtFile;
}dummy;

fstream file1;
file1.open("filename.txt",ios::binary);

if(!file1)
{
    cout<<"\n error opening file \n";
}
else
{
    while(1)
    {
         if(file1.eof()!=0)
             {break;}
         else
         {//
           file1.read(dummy.data,994);
           sendto(connfd,(struct packet*)&dummy,sizeof(struct packet),0,
                  (sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
         }  
    }
}
```

Comment: how is the data stored in the text file?

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: `file in binary line by line` I stopped reading at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
while(1)
{
     if(file1.eof()!=0)
         {break;}
     else
     {//
       file1.read(dummy.data,994);
       sendto(connfd,(struct packet*)&dummy,sizeof(struct packet),0,(sockaddr          *)&server,sizeof(server));
     }
```

...looks like it works out as basically a long-winded way of simulating the `while (!file1.eof())` that many answers talk about as essentially a guaranteed problem. I'd probably write it as:

```
while (file1.read(...))
    sendto(...);
```

I think, however, I'd go a step further, and overload at least `operator>>` (and possibly `operator>>`) for the `packet` type:

```
struct packet { 
    // ...

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, packet &p) { 
        return is.read(p.data, sizeof(p.data));
    }

    // and possibly:    
    friend UDP_iterator operator<<(udp_iterator &c, packet &p) { 
        return sendto(c.fd, &p, sizeof(p), 0, c.server, sizeof(c.server));
    }
};
```

...where a `udp_iterator` would be analogous to an `ostream_iterator`, but would write to a socket instead of a stream. Note that there are a number of similar classes around. Most provide a stream buffer class that connects to a TCP socket, but a UDP socket shouldn't add any great difficulty.

With those overloaded correctly, you should be able to copy the data from the file to the socket with something like this:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<packet>(file1),
          std::istream_iterator<packet>(),
          UDP_iterator<packet>(server));
```